# Remove border/frame around png in latex?

Tags: image, latex, png

I saved an excel graphic in Paint as a .png, and then inserted it in a LaTeX document I'm writing, using the following code:

"bla bla...Figure `~\ref{fig:AQmDQmHCQ}` shows the relationship between bla bla bla, all three calculated as kWh per month:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2.5in]{AQmDQmHCQ}
  \caption{Visualising delivery minimum levels}
  \label{fig:AQmDQmHCQ}
\end{figure}
```

The problems:

1. I get a strange border around the image/figure. The border snugs to upper and lower image bounds, but to the right it fills the whole page, even though the figure finishes well before the center.
2. It floats. i don't like things that float. It shows up in the next section which doesn't have anything to do with the subject of the figure.

EDIT: putting in pic:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the strange border you're seeing?  It's not clear from the code in the question what this would be.

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough "reputations" (need 10)! And someone -1'ed me so instead of 6 I now have 4, which is kind of unfair since I actually always try for several hours by myself.

Comment: +1 for trying to upload.  Now you've got 11 and can upload. :)

Comment: 1: it looks like there's some code you're not showing us, because `includegraphics` doesn't put a border around things.  Are you using an `\fbox` or `\framebox` or something?  2: Are you sure that the image itself doesn't have a bunch of extra space to the right? Unless you resized the image in Paint, all that extra space would be saved into the image, too.

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! I actually had this in the header: \floatstyle{boxed}. I outcommented it and now the pic is ok! I must have put it there for a reason, but didn't comment it, so maybe some other formatting just disappeared...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/latex-is-putting-a-border-around-my-figures

Comment: in my case i removed: \floatstyle{boxed}